# Not Getting location using locationManager On alps x01 watch

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am trying to get location at regular interval but i get the location on device but not able to get location on alps x01 watch watch.

Reference:- http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/2015-new-X01-android-Smart-Watch-phone-1-54-240-240-screen-dual-core-512-4GB/1749427_32335487242.html

```
  LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, MainActivity.this);
                }
                if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, MainActivity.this);
                }
 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("location","lat = " + location.getLatitude() + " lng = " + location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "lat = " + location.getLatitude() + " lng = " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```